Whats the difference between decltype(type) and decltype(vector_of_type)?
I've got a problem with decltype which doesn't work for vector.
Vector Eq is the same type as holder and itemGrabbed:
item* itemGrabbed;
item* holder;
std::vector<std::vector<item*>> Eq;

Everything is initialized, etc.
Eq stores pointers to "inherited" objects - for example, objects from class itemAxe.
Every item class and inherited objects have the same constructor with this argument -> grapicsData:
this->itemGrabbed = new std::remove_pointer<decltype(Eq[x][y]) > ::type{graphicsData};
this->itemGrabbed = new std::remove_pointer<decltype(holder) > ::type{graphicsData};

I guess I could just go with something like this:
item* temp=Eq[x][y];
this->itemGrabbed = new std::remove_pointer<decltype(temp) > ::type{graphicsData};

But I was wondering if it is possible to do it without temp?
The problem is that the 2nd option works but I need to use the 1st one. All that because I need different assign and copy operators.
How can I achieve this?

decltype is resolved in compilation I guess thats answear the question, so how I can get the type of class in runtime?

"Vector Eq is the same type as holder and itemGrabbed." -- No. Elements of elements of Eq are the same type as the other two variables, but a vector of X is not the same type as X. Did you intend to refer to elements instead of the vector? That would better match your code.

"wondering if it is possible to do it" -- What exactly is "it"? You described your setup and showed some code, but you did not state what your goal is. Why are you using decltype? What do you think you gain from such verbosity?

Eq[x][y] thats exactly what im trying to use in decltype, the problem is that decltype isnt good for my case

item has different update() function than itemAxe. The next step is *this->itemGrabbed = *Eq[x][y]; and later im assigning this somewhere else thats why I need this to be exact class pointer, Ive got copy and =operator ready

Apparently you are trying to solve a different problem than your example indicated. As far as I understand from your comments you are trying to create a clone of the actual data type held by pointer in vector. Sometimes it's called a "virtual constructor. " For that, you need to create a virtual clone() function in the classes you want to be cloned usually returning newly copy-constructed object.

@MateuszBiernat "Eq[x][y] thats exactly what im trying to use in decltype" -- Not according to your question's title. Not according to your question's text (excluding the code). The next person with the same question should not have to assume the title is wrong and dig down to your code to find out if this is the same question as theirs.

decltype is resolved by the compiler, at compilation time.
It does not (and cannot) take into account if a pointer to a base class refers to an instance of a derived class during runtime.
In your case:
holder and temp are both of type item*, and so the compiler will resolve these 2 decltypes usages in your question to item*. After applying std::remove_pointer they will become item (and you'll be able to new them).
As for Eq[x][y] - it is actually if type item*& (a reference to item*) and will stay the same after applying std::remove_pointer. Since you cannot use new with a refernce type, you will get a compilation error.
MSVC for example issues this error for it:
error C2464: '_Ty': cannot use 'new' to allocate a reference
     with
     [
            _Ty=item *&
     ]

Regarding type inference in runtime (asked about in comments):
C++ does not support full reflection, and so you cannot inspect the type of an object in runtime and use this type as is to create a new instance.
You will need to implement some code to do this heavy lifting, e.g. some kind of factory.
You can start with this post: Possible to instantiate object given its type in C++?.

Thanks man! How can I get a type in runtime then?

Added some info about it.

I guess thats enough info from you friend :) Thank you very much. I'll check it out

While your main point is correct (no compile-time reflection possible for runtime inheritance, so there won't be item type cloning with this appoach), there's an error in your answer, and this also sort of answers the question as asked initially. Eq[x][y] is not of type item*; it is of type item*&. std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(Eq[x][y])> would still be item*&, and new of that type wouldn't work (this is in regard to "option 1 vs option 2" in the question, why temporary helps).

@AndreyTurkin you are right. I updated my answer.

I used factory pattern which works perfectly here

@Mateusz good to hear.
